# Combobox placeholder text theme brush ( text color )

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to change the placeholder text color of a combobox in windows store app ( XAML / C# )

Here's the code behind:

```
List<string> orderType = new List<string>();
orderType.Add("ANS");
orderType.Add("DG");
orderType.Add("LAB");
orderType.Add("RAD");
ComboBox orderTypeComboBox = new ComboBox();
orderTypeComboBox.ItemsSource = orderType;
orderTypeComboBox.Header = "Order Type";
orderTypeComboBox.PlaceholderText = "Choose Order Type";
orderTypeComboBox.SelectionChanged += orderTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged;
```

The placeholder text default color is black, I want it white.

Here's what I tried (globally) but it failed:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush" Color="White" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And I couldn't locate "generic.xaml" file to search for the right key for the "SolidColorBrush"

Answer (score 1):

What you need to change to affect the Placeholder's color is the `SystemControlPageTextBaseHighBrush` property:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageTextBaseHighBrush" Color="Green" />
```

**Warning:** Unfortunately this does not only effect your ComboBox but also many other controls. The clean way is creating a custom ComboBox style with a modified foreground color for the Placeholder element.

If you need help with creating a new style, please take a look at [this code](https://gist.github.com/einRobby/cc51e50d18b678d927c6), where you can copy the modified style, if you want.